# Why finalize() method in java is not in Finalizer class? Why it is defined in Object Class?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

Why finalize() method in java is not in Finalizer class?
Why it is defined in Object Class?

Comment: Because the goal is to be able to finalize any object, and not just instances of Finalizer.

Answer (score 3):

Look at javadoc about the method `finalize()`

> Called by the garbage collector **on an object** (that object may be any object that is why it's declared in the object class and not in the finalizer class) when garbage collection
>   determines that **there are no more references to the object**.

You **can override** this method on any classes to specify what to do when a given object is collected by garbage collector.

Answer (score 3):

1. The "Finalizer" class, [java.lang.ref.Finalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) and the "finalizer()" method, [java.object.finalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) are two separate, distinct things.
2. As alexey noted about "finalize()",

> You can override [finalize()] ... to specify what to do when
>   a given object is collected by garbage collector.

3. The purpose, role and lifetime of the "Finalizer class" is discussed here:

> http://www.fasterj.com/articles/finalizer2.shtml
>
> The JVM will ignore a trivial finalize() method ... Otherwise, if an
>   instance is being created, and that instance has a non-trivial
>   finalize() method defined or inherited, then the JVM will do the
>   following:
>
> - The JVM will create the instance
> - The JVM will also create an instance of the java.lang.ref.Finalizer class, pointing to that object instance just created (and pointing to
>     a queue that it will be put on by the GC)
> - The java.lang.ref.Finalizer class holds on to the    java.lang.ref.Finalizer instance that was just created (so that it is 
>     kept alive, otherwise nothing would keep it alive and it would be
>     GCed at the next GC).

4. So to answer your question: "finalize()" is something *YOU* do (to customize the cleanup behavior of your object during GC); "Finalize" is an object the *JVM* creates (to facilitate and manage that cleanup).
5. For many reasons, including both [performance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19636-01/819-2561/6n4rfhrjt/) and [security](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MET12-J.+Do+not+use+finalizers), it's generally a *bad* idea to create your own, custom finalizer unless you absolutely have to.